# No server drop dwon menu showing in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm wanting to publish a workbook to Tableau public, by following [these](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/publish_workbooks_tableaupublic.htm) steps which say to click on the "server" drop-down menu then sign into Tableau public etc. But I have no "Server" menu. I Thought maybe I should try updating to the latest version, so I downloaded the newest version from their website but the same thing happened. Anyone know what's up with this?

[No server menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z2Dd.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You're using Tableau Public. Therefore just hit the Save icon or File - Save (or Save As) and it'll push your workbook to the Tableau Public server.

The instructions you provided refer to using standard paid Tableau Desktop.